# Notepad++ instant search

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I am searching for a plugin or stuff that will allow to instantly search in notepad++... Like Visual Studio search does...

[image]

I mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and when hitting by eg. <kbd>tes</kbd> immediately first occurence of `tes` in the text be underlined (ne need to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notepad++ has a similar feature built-in: Press `Ctrl+Alt+I` or choose [`Incremental Search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search) from the `Search` menu.

Comment: This is great, but I wish there was a way to do incremental searches with regex. :P